# Django Rest Framework Uploaded File Url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django rest framework automatically generates urls for uploaded files. However, the url it automatically generates doesn't actually point to where the file is stored. For example, I upload a file to my api named `example.txt` and this is what the object in my database looks like after the upload:

```
{
    name: "John Doe",
    bio: "localhost:8000/api/users/static/example.txt"
}
```

My static directory is located in the root directory so the file actually lives and can be accessed at `localhost:8000/static/example.txt`. The automatically generated url returns a 404. How can I overwrite the automatically generated url to be the correct one?

Here's what my model looks like:

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
   bio = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='static')
```

Here's what the serializer looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ("name", "bio")
```

Comment: Can you add the code in your serializer?

Comment: Just updated it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your MEDIA_URL and your MEDIA_ROOT into you settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

And add to your urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

MEDIA_ROOT is the absolute path where your file gonna be saved. And MEDIA_URL is the url that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. And I should change `upload_at=static` to  `upload_to=bio/files`, just because static path is for just static files as .css, .js and image files.

Comment: @zjwhi remember that in deploy(DEBUG = TRUE), your media is server by the host!